# A question on Horsemanship

Tags: magic-the-gathering

This question is more around the fun of playing decks casually.  Horsemanship I believe is legal in Commander and Legacy.  However, if you wanted to enjoy some casual games with a Portal Three Kingdom deck against some Modern or Standard decks, would it be necessary to treat Horsemanship the same as Flying and allow cards that have Reach or cards that counter the Flying ability to be used against Horsemanship?

Comment: Changing the question after it has been answered is generally frowned upon. Also it means the answer can change after new sets are released and new preconstructed decks are released as they will all be built around different abilities.

Comment: Hi John, my intent was not to change it, but your closure response reads as follows which makes it very confusing:  Update the question so it can be answered with facts and citations. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one. ps... you show edit and delete.  But by delete it warns you about getting penalized.  So its unclear for newcomer whose question is closed on what to do.  Either leave alone or edit or delete it?

Comment: The problem is you already have an answer to the question that would be invalidated because your question is now focused on pre-constructed decks which is a problem. Not only that the answers would be valid only for specific decks and would need new answers as new pre-constructed decks where released. Don't forget the close votes started before the question had an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you suggest was certainly thought about by WotC [when they allowed the *Portal* cards into Vintage and Legacy](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/more-about-march-1st-2005-03-11):

> Should we errata it so that horsemanship creatures can be blocked by fliers?
> In the end we realized that we were kidding ourselves—the creatures with that ability just aren't aggressive enough to worry about, so we left the ability alone. If you want to play horsemanship in constructed, knock yourself out.

so it's not an entirely stupid suggestion - but in casual games, your best bet is probably just to try it and see if they feel overpowered; the answer will probably depend enormously on the power level of the Standard/Modern decks you're playing.

Comment: To add to my question, I became a little unsure about fair play, when I read the text on [mtg: Sun Quan, Lord of Wu]: > Creatures you control have horsemanship. (They can't be blocked except by creatures with horsemanship.) I was visualizing a deck of approx. 20 creature cards all unlockable ranging from 1/1 to 4/4.

Comment: Sure, but you're talking about a 6 CMC card there which is easily removable. Even in Standard, a 6 CMC card should be a "must answer" threat. Probably not even playable in reasonably competitive Modern.

Comment: @Spaciousmind Sun Quan reads similarily to [mtg:Archetype of Imagination] - sure, slightly better stats and no interaction with reach. But given that the Archetype was printed at uncommon and never made waves in constructed suggests to me that this kind of effect on a 6CMC creature is not something you have to worry about.